# in laravel is posssible to store pressent time with pre-defined text in database,

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i want to store present time and date along with pre-defined text in database,

like

"WELCOME 2019-12-10 16:06:36"

now it just storing date time only "2019-12-10 16:06:36"

**i was tried but it showing error**

```
"Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string"
```

**my code**

```
$user['hello'] = "welcome".new \DateTime('NOW');
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @Prashant Deshmukh "Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont try and do everything in one line of code as you need to format the date objects internal date in order to print it

```
$d = new \DateTime('NOW');
$user['hello'] = "welcome " . $d->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

RESULT

```
Array
(
    [hello] => welcome 2019-12-10 11:02:11
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  $user['hello'] = "welcome ".now();
```